# access helpers options in view cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Let's say in my `app_controller.php` I include a helper like this:

```
var $helpers = array('MyHelper' => array('value' => 'This is a value'));
```

As you can see above, I'm also setting an array to my Helper. How do I access this array in my view files? Anybody knows how I can do this?

Comment: `var` is deprecated dont use it, use `public`,`protected` or `private`

Answer (score 1):

In your view: what happens if you try and access the options member variable just like you would a function?

```
<?php
    ...
    ...
    debug( $this->MyHelper->options['value'] );
    // or
    debug( $this->MyHelper->options );
    // to view the whole array - access them by key like above
    ...
?>
```

Instead of downvoting you should read the answer @thecodeparadox gave you as he explicitly solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

it will be accessible thru:

```
$helpers["Myhelper"]["value"];
```

Comment: It's should work check out this official description of array functionality [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) see example #7

Comment: @user765368 and give more code lines before ask something. If you want get the right answer of course :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyHelper extends AppHelper {
    public $options = array();
    public function __construct(View $view, $option = array()) {
        parent::__construct($view, $option);
        $this->options = $option;
        debug($option); // with in $option you will get your array
    }
}

class AppController extends Controller {
    public $helpers = array('MyHelper' => array('option1' => 'value1'));
}
```

Then try in your view file

```
$this->MyHelper->options;
```

Comment: My question was, `How do I access this array in my view files` when I use my helper